# Ruby on rails, delayed jobs with rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I want to start workes for the job directly after some certain method. So, I start the application with usual rails s. Upload some stuff, so the create method is invoked. After create method the :perform_analysis -method is delayed. Some data is inserted into delayed_jobs table. Normally I start the workers to work typing `"script/delayed_job start"` in the command line. But I would like to start the workers work automatically, so I will type nothing.

model:

```
after_create :perform_analysis
def perform_analysis
bla
end
handle_asynchronously :perform_analysis, :run_at => Proc.new { 5.minutes.from_now }
```

So, I run an application with rails s. I log in in my wep-page. Upload some files, after 5 min the jobs are delayed. Then the worker should start to work. 
I have found [this page](http://shouweick.blogspot.de/2012/12/delayed-job-real-pain-in-production.html) that does almost what I want but somehow the workers do not start at all. So the `schedule.rb` is  not run. Should I do something more that is not told on that webpage?

Is there any other possibility do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you take a look at Foreman (http://ddollar.github.com/foreman/) and have your procfile declare a worker process:

```
web: bundle exec rails s
worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

This way, a single command `foreman start` will start both the server and worker. The output will be presented in the same window for both.

Comment: Is'n it possible to start the worker just in some min after create method?

Comment: I haven't seen that setup before. Do you have a reason not to keep the working running?